# Why do EC2 instances sometimes end up giving a very high IRQ load in htop?

Tags: amazon-ec2, htop, irq

We have a couple of **t3.small** instances. This is what the CPU utilization graph ends up looking like for both of them (running similar programs).

[image: Instance 1]

[image: Instance 2]

Both seem to end up stabilizing at 20% CPU utilization. When I look at htop, this is what I see.

[image: htop]

Why is this happening? I must also point out that there seems to be a weird correlation between the the CPU utilization graph and the **CPU credit usage** graph. Both fall in tandem, but I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Baseline vCPU utilization rates are given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html).